# Is there a way to access ITokenAcquisition from a static class in .NET Core 6.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have multiple services in my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application that make http calls to a backend API and all of them need to have the calls to be authenticated with bearer token.

Instead of having to instantiate the `ITokenAcquisition` in each registered service class, is there a way to have it instantiated in a helper class like I do for the `HttpClient` in the example below?

```
public class XYZService : IXYZService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

    public XYZService(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
    {
        _httpClient = Helpers.Helper.HttpClient().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, You can return an instance of `ITokenAcquisition` in a static class, But I don't think it is a good method, It will increase coupling in your project.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you can pass to the static class' methods any service the static class' method needs to complete its job.  However, it pretty much makes no sense.  Why?  Well, let's use your particular case as example.  The static class needs token information.  Instead of giving it the service that retrieves token information, you can just pass the token information.

Anyway, in general, you can do this:

```cs
public static class SomeClass
{
    public static void DoSomething(ITokenAcquisition taService)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That should accomplish what you need.  However, what prevents you to write the following, instead?

```cs
public static class SomeClass
{
    public static void DoSomething(TokenData data)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The second one is friendlier, especially for unit testing:  Now you have one less mocking to do.

Still, working with token data in a static class the way you want it is kind of dangerous.  Tokens vary on the HTTP request being processed.  You would have to make your ITokenAcquisition service implementation smart enough to retrieve the correct information for the current thread.  Why complicate things like this?